# Grouping plots in Tensorboard

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I would like to organize my plots in Tensorboard into groups.

For example, say I'm training several networks at the same time, they each have their own accuracy and loss wrt step, and it would be nice to group accuracy and loss by its network. Or maybe I want to inspect the activation, average weight, average biases of each layer, grouped by their layer, to better understand how they change during training.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# define first network
model_1 = tf.layers.dense(input1 , 100)
...
loss_1 = ...
summaries_1 = tf.summary.merge([tf.summary.scalar("loss_1", loss_1)])
train_op_1 = ...


# define second network
model_2 = tf.layers.dense(input2 , 100)
...
loss_2 = ...
summaries_2 = tf.summary.merge([tf.summary.scalar("loss_2", loss_2)])
train_op_2 = ...


#define file writer
fw = tf.summary.FileWriter(logdir='/tmp/my_logs')


sess = tf.Session()
# train your networks

for i in range(NUM_ITR):

    # train first net
    _, summary_str = sess.run([train_op_1, summaries_1])
    fw.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=i)

    # train second net
    _, summary_str = sess.run([train_op_2, summaries_2])
    fw.add_summary(summary_str, global_step=i)
```

Comment: This answer does not seem to address what I am asking. There are several things I'm recording into tensorboard for each network. And it's the same for each network. So how can I group them by network?

Comment: ok.. I think I understand now - for instance you would like to have loss1,loss2,loss3 of three different network on the same group side by side and accuracy_1,accuracy_2,accuracy_3 in different group side by side?